# Kafka Static membership in AWS ECS

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, amazon-ecs, distributed-system

I am trying to avail the Kafka clients static membership feature in my applications. A challenge I am facing is that my application runs on AWS ECS service and it’s difficult to have a static ID on each ECS task, which can be retained even a task fails and new comes in place.

I wanted to check if anybody has tried this to achieve it with the AWS ECS service. I am looking for if there is an out-of-the-box solution for it, instead of me creating a custom solution for my need.

Also, suggestions on a custom solution would also be helpful.

Comment: Containers are meant to be ephemeral. If you want something static and unchanging, use EC2

Comment: Lets say, unfortunately this is not possible for me.

Comment: Then launch containers with some environment variable that "assigns" static ids to them

Comment: How will you assign different environment variables to different task?

Comment: Maybe use one replica for each task? I'm sure there are other solutions, but you're obviously going to need something that is a constant value at runtime, but that's going to have to be in your control rather than decided by the platform

Comment: Didn't get what you meant by task replica. Though I am thinking to have a shared state in redis, and on application startup i will figure out the id to be used. But it involves locking, and logic is getting complex considering the scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

AWS container service team member here. This may be slightly generic for a Stackoverflow question but the ask is legit. Today there is no easy way to achieve that but it's something our users have been asking. We are considering adding this ability in the future. You can track the advancements of this and the discussions around it in [this GH issue on the public roadamap](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/127).